# Error 500 Internal Server Error after changing Joomla user configuration

Tags: joomla

I've changed the users permissions from the Joomla panel control and now it doesn't show the global configuration anymore . The errors it gives me is the following "500 Internal Server Error".

These are the errors logs:

> Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:51:01 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] -
>   www.mydomain.it - End of script output before headers: index.php,
>   referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=levels
>   Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:50:37 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] -
>   www.mydomain.it - End of script output before headers: index.php,
>   referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=levels
>   Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:50:08 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] -
>   www.mydomain.it - End of script output before headers: index.php,
>   referer http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php Wed, 25 Jul
>   2018 14:50:08 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] - www.mydomain.it -
>   End of script output before headers: index.php, referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php Wed, 25 Jul 2018
>   14:23:34 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] - www.mydomain.it - End of
>   script output before headers: index.php, referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php?option=com_users&view=levels
>   Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:20:50 GMT [error] [client 93.47.231.223] -
>   www.mydomain.it - End of script output before headers: index.php,
>   referer http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php Wed, 25 Jul
>   2018 12:42:42 GMT [error] [client 62.19.166.145] - www.mydomain.it -
>   End of script output before headers: index.php, referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/ Wed, 25 Jul 2018 12:40:12 GMT
>   [error] [client 62.19.166.145] - www.mydomain.it - End of script
>   output before headers: index.php, referer
>   http://www.mydomain.it/administrator/index.php?option=com_postinstall&eid=700
>   Tue, 24 Jul 2018 21:10:00 GMT [notice] - www.mydomain.it - AH00163:
>   Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations Tue, 24
>   Jul 2018 21:10:00 GMT [notice] - www.mydomain.it - AH00094: Command
>   line: '/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Can you please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: After I've changed a permission from user to group it gives me the following error : Internal Server Error

Comment: Try disabling extensions using PHPMyAdmin or similar on your web host. There are [many possible reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=joomla+End+of+script+output+before+headers:+index.php+site:forum.joomla.org&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS778US778&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpstDyyrrcAhVk7IMKHaD6Dq0QrQIINSgEMAA&biw=1026&bih=1149&dpr=1) for this problem.